# Invalid quantifier error

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to apply a regex in javascript but I receive the following error `Syntax Error: invalid quantifier`

```
(?x)^(?:https?://)?
        (?:(?:(?:www\.|m\.)?soundcloud\.com/
            (?P<uploader>[\w\d-]+)/
            (?!sets/)(?P<title>[\w\d-]+)
        )
    )
```

Here's an example using the same regex

```
var regex = '(?x)^(?:https?://)?(?:(?:(?:www\.|m\.)?soundcloud\.com/(?P<uploader>[\w\d-]+)/(?!sets/)(?P<title>[\w\d-]+)))';
var url = 'https://soundcloud.com/lordemusic/tennis-court';
var match = url.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

According to a javascript regex linter it says `Unexpected character "x" after "?"`

What is causing the error and how can I change the regex to make it work?  Also if named capturing groups are causing the error, how can I replace the named capturing groups with numerical indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several 'flavor' problems with your regex.

- The free-spacing mode `(?x)` is not available in JavaScript
- JavaScript does not support named capture

This would be a close conversion that is valid in JavaScript:

Here is some JavaScript code to get you started retrieving the content of the groups (see online [demo](http://js.do/code/39693)).

```
<script>
var subject = 'https://soundcloud.com/lordemusic/tennis-court';
var regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:(?:www\.|m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/([\w\d-]+)\/(?!sets\/)([\w\d-]+)))/i;
var match = regex.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    var group1 = match[1];
    var group2 = match[2];
    document.write(group1, "<br>");
    document.write(group2, "<br>");
} else {
    result = "";
}

</script>
```

Comment: How do I rewrite the regex to replace the named capturing groups with numerical indexes?

Comment: Is there a way I can get the uploader and title from the `match` array like `match[0]` or `match[1]`?  It doesn't seem like those two elements of the array are being set, whereas the regex implemented in php would have those elements set.

Comment: hmm that returns an empty result for `var match = regex.exec('https://soundcloud.com/lordemusic/tennis-court');` which should be a valid url

Comment: FYI, added code to the question to give you group1 and group2. Yes, I show your url as matching. :)